# How to import a menu button and run a function if triggered? (PyQt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have imported a menu bar button from "Design.ui" and tried to assign functions to it but it seems like there is an error.

Imported design.ui --> `uic.loadUi("Design.ui", self)`

Then importing the menu button from design.ui `self.openFileButton = self.findChild(QStatusBar, "actionOpen")`

(Error : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'triggered' ) Then trying to assign functions in it and getting the error, `self.openFileButton.triggered.connect(self.openImage)`

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: `self.findChild(QStatusBar, 'actionOpen')` tries to find any child object of type QStatusBar. Seeing your last line, you're probably trying to reach a QAction, so it should be `self.findChild(QAction, 'actionOpen')`. In any case, as expained in the current answer, you don't need to use `findChild` at all, as `uic` already creates attributes for the instance.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `uic.loadUi()`, you should be able to to directly use the QWidgets you created in the `.ui` file instead of calling `self.findChild()`

For example:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):
      QWidget.__init__(self)   
      uic.loadUi("Design.ui", self)
      self.openFileButton.triggered.connect(self.openImage)

   def openImage(self):
      # Does some code
```

Alternatively, you can set the loaded UI as a variable and use the widgets from there.

For Example:

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):
      QWidget.__init__(self)   
      self.ui = uic.loadUi("Design.ui", self)
      self.ui.openFileButton.triggered.connect(self.openImage)

   def openImage(self):
      # Does some code
```

Comment: It should be `self.ui = ...`, but `uic.loadUi()` actually creates the attributes for the `self` object anyway, so it's actually unnecessary, as the object will be available as both `self.ui.openFileButton` and `self.openFileButton`.